# Modify position in a line if Regular Expression found

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I need to modify the positions number 10 of every line that finds the word 'Example' (can´t use the actual data here) and add the string '(ID) '. **It doesn´t necessarily have to begin with 9 numbers, it just needs to add the string to the position number 10**.
For example, this line should be modified like this:

- ORIGINAL: 123456789This line is being used as an Example
- SOLUTION: 123456789(ID) This line is being used as an Example

So far I have this, to find the Example and copy the rest of the line as to not lose the text:

```
Find: (.*)Example
```

Bonus points if it works for two different words 'Example1' and 'Example2' in different sentences, the 'and also' part of this example would change in every line.

- ORIGINAL: 123456789This line is being used as an Example1 and also Example2
- SOLUTION: 123456789(ID) This line is being used as an Example1 and also Example2

This would have this search:

```
Find: (.*)Example1(.*)Example2
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
Find:    (\d{9})(?=.*\bExample1\b.*\bExample2\b)
Replace: $(ID) 
               ^^^ single space after (ID)
```

### Demo

The regex pattern used matches and captures a 9 digit number (you may adjust to any width, or range of widths, which you want).  It also uses a positive lookahead to assert that `Example1` and `Example2` in fact occur later in the same line:

```
(?=.*\bExample1\b.*\bExample2\b)
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your help but maybe I didn´t  explain it right. I need to add the string in the position number 10 in every line that matches those strings, it doesn´t necesarily have to begin with 9 numbers. Theres also numbers in my file, so it´s replacing those instead of adding it at the begining.

Comment: I have answered the best I could using your actual sample data.  If you have other requirements, then it is on you to reword your question to make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you add characters in a certain position, even tho I accepted Tims answer because it´s very similar and made me figure it out:

`^(\S{9})(?=.*\bExample1\b.*\bExample2\b)`

As you can see, I only added '^' so it´s the position from the start of the line, and 'S' instead of 'd' so it counts characters that are not whitespace, instead of numbers. This should work for any type of line you have.